Notification Provider component causing Hydration errors in NextJS with React Moralis - FCC Pat Collins full stack dev course
I am stuck in lesson 10 and I am unable to progress after the wrapper in my layout.js file in my next app
My Layout.js :
"use client"
import { Inter } from "next/font/google"
import "./globals.css"
import { MoralisProvider } from "react-moralis"
import { NotificationProvider } from "web3uikit"

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] })

/* export const metadata = {
    title: "Smart Contract Lottery FCC",
    description: "Generated by create next app",
} */

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <MoralisProvider initializeOnMount={false}>
            <NotificationProvider>
                <html lang="en">
                    <head>
                        <title>Smart Contract Lottery</title>
                    </head>
                    <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
                </html>
            </NotificationProvider>
        </MoralisProvider>
    )
}

My page.js :
"use client"
import { ConnectButton } from "web3uikit"
import LotteryEntrance from "../../components/LotteryEntrance"
export default function Home() {
    return (
        <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-48">
            <div className="max-w-2xl w-full items-center justify-between font-mono text-5xl">
                Smart Contract Lottery
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-col gap-y-8 max-w-5xl justify-between items-center text-2xl p-12">
                Decentralized Lottery
                <ConnectButton moralisAuth={false} />
                <LotteryEntrance />
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}

The errors I am getting :
app-index.js:33 Warning: In HTML, <div> cannot be a child of <#document>.
This will cause a hydration error.
    at div
    at O2
    
    Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
    
    An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in <#document>.
    
    Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed.
    
     Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
     
     There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
     
     Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
     
     he above error occurred in the <StrictMode> component:


Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

Uncaught AggregateError
    at flushSyncWorkAcrossRoots_impl 

I tried wrapping up the layout.js component in a separate file and exporting it within the layout.js but then it's just the same issue being replicated. Am I missing something?
UPDATE
okay was trying different ways to use the Notification component, and doing this in my page.js took the error away :
                <NotificationProvider>
                    <LotteryEntrance />
                </NotificationProvider>

I am getting this now - but my UI is now getting rendered, previously I didn't get any UI elements :
   app-index.js:33 Warning: Extra attributes from the server: data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded,data-gr-ext-installed
    at body
    at html
    at MoralisProvider (

Any idea why ?

The error mentions -> app-index.js at line 33,  what's inside app-index.js?

@Keith This file is present in next's client directory in node modules. I am guessing it's because of the use client directive?
This is the line that's causing issues :
origConsoleError.apply(window.console, args);


Sorry, I'm not really a NextJS expert, the whole SSR / Hydration stuff is something I'm staying well away from.  Each to there own, but IMO it's going backwards in Dev tech.
